# Python win32com CallNotImplementedError instead of AccessDenied?

Tags: python, python-2.7, access-denied, win32com

This code:

```
import os
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

tempFile = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir), u'_tempfile.tmp')
# print tempFile
dest = os.path.join('C:\Program Files', '_tempfile.tmp')
with open(tempFile, 'wb'): pass # create the file
try: # to move it into C:\Program Files
        result, aborted = shell.SHFileOperation(
                (None, # parent window
                 shellcon.FO_MOVE, tempFile, dest,
                 # 0,
                 shellcon.FOF_SILENT, # replace this with 0 to get a UAC prompt
                 None, None))
        print result, aborted
except: # no exception raised
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Prints `120 False` - [120 being CallNotImplementedError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If the flags are set to 0 then you get a UAC prompt as expected. Now why is not the result `5` (AccessDeniedError) ? Is something not implemented indeed or is it a bug or what do I not get ?

Needless to say that this was hard to debug - I was expecting an access denied and I had to look very closely to see what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misreading the error code. [`SHFileOperation` uses its own set of error codes separate from the system error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); in this case, `0x78`/`120` is:

> `DE_ACCESSDENIEDSRC`: Security settings denied access to the source.

That doesn't seem like it's the likely error (the destination is the problem), but this function is deprecated (replaced in Vista by `IFileOperation`) and while it still exists in Vista+, they may not have been particularly careful about returning entirely accurate error codes for situations (like UAC) that didn't exist pre-Vista.

Per the docs:

> - These are pre-Win32 error codes and are no longer supported or defined in any public header file. To use them, you must either define them yourself or compare against the numerical value.
> - These error codes are subject to change and have historically done so.
> - These values are provided only as an aid in debugging. They should not be regarded as definitive.

Comment: Ah thank you ! I am not using them directly, it's the python module that uses them, and I know about it being deprecated but hey that's what I got in the legacy code I maintain. Mystery solved :)

Comment: And da [legacy code](https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/blob/3b2469e7cb6cbd7e89ac646873f1a6578085181b/Mopy/bash/env.py#L303-L334) - have to go patch this now

Comment: Of interest that if I pass 0 as flag (so the UAC prompt shows up) and I cancel it does give as a result 1223 error which is [ERROR_CANCELLED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: As the docs note "several of its possible return values are based on pre-Win32 error codes, which in some cases overlap the later Winerror.h values without matching their meaning. Those particular values are detailed here, and for these specific values only these meanings should be accepted over the Winerror.h codes." 1223 isn't in the list of errors for this function, so that's a normal `Win32` error code.